# Which set pattern is better to use

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have come across two patterns of adding data to Cloud Firestore.

First is by using transactions, i.e:

```
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async{
  await transaction.set(ref.document(), {
    'user_name': _name.text,
    'age': _age.text
  });
});
```

Second is by using setData() method:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document('$id').setData({
  'user_name': _name.text,
  'age': _age.text
});
```

Is there any performance/good_practice reasoning behind using one or the other? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a transaction when you need an atomic read-then-write operation.  If you don't need to read the data at the location before writing it, then you don't need a transaction at all.

Answer (score 1):

If your same node is updated by different users at the same time then you need to use `runTransaction`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

If the node is updated by only the single user at a time, we can use the setData